# Jhipster: Error: Could not resolve '_' from state 'site'

Tags: angular, jhipster

I am trying to move some of the Administration menu views(i.e. session,API etc ) inside new Menu called Maintenence. I have created the folder inside app with updated files and changed the index.html also with the new path. Whenever I am trying to access this state I am getting Error: Could not resolve  '_' from state 'site'. Is there is anything I am missing?

Folder structure:

[image]

```
       part of index.html            

        <script src="scripts/app/maintenance/sessions/sessions.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/app/maintenance/sessions/sessions.controller.js">   </script> 


        part of sessions.js

            'use strict';

            angular.module('customerApp')
                .config(function ($stateProvider) {
                    $stateProvider
                        .state('sessions', {
                            parent: 'maintenance',
                            url: '/sessions',
                            data: {
                                authorities: ['ROLE_SUPERADMIN'],
                                pageTitle: 'global.menu.account.sessions'
                            },
                            views: {
                                'content@': {
                                    templateUrl: 'scripts/app/maintenance/sessions/sessions.html',
                                    controller: 'SessionsController'
                                }
                            },
                            resolve: {
                                translatePartialLoader: ['$translate', '$translatePartialLoader', function ($translate, $translatePartialLoader) {
                                    $translatePartialLoader.addPart('sessions');
                                    return $translate.refresh();
                                }]
                            }
                        });
                });

maintenance.js

'use strict';

angular.module('customerApp')
    .config(function ($stateProvider) {
        $stateProvider
            .state('maintenance', {
                abstract: true,
                parent: 'site'
            });
    });
```